# Minimal bounding quadrilateral of a convex polygon

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons

I am looking at the problem of finding the quadrilateral of minimum area that encloses a convex polygon.

I found the following articles:

1. An Optimal Algorithm for Finding Minimal Enclosing Triangles by Joseph O'Rourke, Alok Aggarwal, Sanjeev Maddila, and Michael Baldwin, in time $O(n)$, for triangles;
2. Implementation of linear minimum area enclosing triangle algorithm by Ovidiu Pârvu and David Gilbert, detailing an implementation of the above algorithm;
3. Minimum area circumscribing Polygons by Alok Aggarwal, J.S. Chang , and Chee K. Yap, in time $O(n^2\log n\log k)$ for a $k$-gon;
4. Geometric applications of a matrix-searching algorithm by Alok Aggarwal, Maria M. Klawe, Shlomo Moran, Peter Shor and Robert Wilber, in time $O(n^2\log k)$.

Not counting the fact that these methods are far for being easy to understand and that the fourth one is not really explained in the paper, I am after a practical implementation that would not exceed the complexity  $O(n^2\log n)$ for a quadrilateral.

Can anybody help me ?

I also have the feeling that a solution for the quadrilateral can be drawn from a solution for triangles, by considering a lemma in 3. that allows to split the problem in two sub-problems by considering a pair of edges.

Can anybody confirm a connection between the triangular and quadrangular cases ?